# What are resources to build parts of a Web Application in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to learn Rust and am coming from a web application background. My past experience is React, React Native, Node.js, Java (Springboot), and Angular.

My question is can a server or a user interface be built on Rust? I imagine it's possible today. Where can I go to for learning how?

Comment: Rust has a very well-written book and [a good discord server](https://discord.com/invite/rust-lang).

Comment: Thanks for showing me the discord! Just joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can build both a web server and a web application in rust. If you don’t know any rust, I would get started with the Rust Book which you can find on rust’s website.

If you want to build a web application, the crate, Yew, is the best in my opinion. It does state it’s not production ready but fine for personal projects. Coming from rust, it should feel similar ( but obviously different because rust and JavaScript are a lot different ). It even has a JSX like implementation.

There are plenty of web server crates you can use. The fastest being Actix-web. Other crates for web servers include Rocket, warp, & tower. All have documentation and tutorials if you google for their github repo.

Comment: Great! I'll look into those.